# Juniper Private VLAN isolated port on a trunk

Tags: vlan, juniper, private-vlan

I'm trying to grasp the private VLAN configuration on Juniper EX switches.

As I understand it right now:

- Access ports in the primary VLAN (VLAN with `no-local-switching` configured) are implicitly isolated ports
- Trunk ports in the primary VLAN with `pvlan-trunk` set are PVLAN trunk interfaces
- All other trunk ports in the primary VLAN are promiscuous ports

Is there any way to configure a trunk port to be a isolated port in a PVLAN?

Background: A host has a NIC with multiple VLANs configured. On the switch this is a trunk port accordingly. I want the switchport to be an isolated port in the private VLAN.

Comment: What OS is the host? I could assume ESXi/vSphere? Have you also review this: http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos10.4/topics/concept/private-vlans-ex-series.html ?

Comment: I have reviewed private VLANs, I'm actually using them. ;) The host is a normal host, no virtualisation or anything. But that wouldn't make a difference anyway. The host (OS) has no influence over PVLANs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not.  This is a frustrating limitation of the way Juniper have implemented Isolated ports and Promiscuos ports in PVLANs - it essentially boils down to if the interfaces is in **access** mode, it's an **Isolated** port, but if it's **tagged**, it's a **Promiscuous** port.

This https://mellowd.co.uk/ccie/?p=5387 is worth a read if you haven't seen it already - goes into a bit more detail than the Juniper Support documentation examples.

Comment: the link seems broken, perhaps this is the right page: https://web.archive.org/web/20140919200350/https://mellowd.co.uk/ccie/?p=5387 (Though I think the configuration syntax may have changed too)